# How to wait for existing PHP connections to close in Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx

For upgrading a site running nginx/php, we're following something similar to:

https://www.calazan.com/how-to-configure-nginx-so-you-can-quickly-put-your-website-into-maintenance-mode/

```
server {
    ...
    location / {
        if (-f /siteroot/maintenance_on.html) {
            return 503;
        }


        ...
    }


    # Error pages.
    error_page 503 /maintenance_on.html;
    location = /maintenance_on.html {
        root /siteroot/glucosetracker/;
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is, after I create maintenance_on.html, how can I wait for any outstanding PHP connections to close?

Comment: What do you mean by wait ? Any existing connections won't be affected, only new ones will be served a 503.

Comment: Exactly. The question only pertains to the existing connections that may take a while to complete, not the new ones.

Comment: So you want to know whether existing connections are still open, right ? Please clarify that in your question. ("how can I wait" looks unclear to me, I would've answered just grab a coffee and wait ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use netstat in a script to test for open connections and loop until they are closed before performing maintenance. Or forcefully close them.